# How do I update cells from dynamic dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Ok so I know how to make dynamic dropdown menus across sheets, but if I change one of the options in the dynamic dropdown how do I make it so if the option was already selected in the dropdown it changes with it? For example in the image I've attached to this post, if 'test 1' is selected in all the dropdowns but is then changed to 'test 10' how do I make the cells that had 'test 1' selected automatically change to 'test 10'?

[image]

I've tried messing around with some options built into sheets with no luck. I have an idea of how to do it with app script but I wasn't sure if this was the best path for solving this issue.

Comment: Can you share a sample spreadsheet with the expected result? Please remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Yes. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1czMA4M84Meu77EezzrifWlvnBLt_OL2DqjSTVma_ln4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a screenshot of expected result so we can understand your goal

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @Logan Consider asking for text tables  instead.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)